# Friendly URL type Onepage

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

I have a problem, I'm writing a website type onepage and I want to do friendly links, but I don't know how can I do this.

The result that I have: examplepage.com/#about
The result that I want to have: examplepage.com/about-me

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please give more details and examples of what you have tried so far so others can better understand your request

Comment: I want to remove # from url.  HTML: <a href="#about">About</a>  
And i wanna have those such URL: examplepage.com/about-me

Comment: What do you mean by "onepage"? Do you refer to a "single page application"?

Comment: Rewriting from "/about-me" to "#about" does not really make sense...  An anchor like "#about" is a client side notation, but rewriting takes place on the server side. Though it would technically be possible to rewrite or redirect an incoming request `/about-me` to something containing such anchor I fail to see what that should accomplish...

Comment: For that kind of routing with a single-page application, you should look into the HTML5 History API.